# Where are Firebase 'daily private backups' stored?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I upgraded to the 'Flame' subscription for $25 a month since it supports [Daily private backups](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

Daily backups are supposed to be uploaded to Google Cloud Storage Or Amazon S3.

> **What are daily private backups? Do you offer hourly backups?**
>
> Private backups is an advanced feature for customers on our paid plans, that backs up your Firebase Realtime Database data once a day and uploads it to Google Cloud Storage or Amazon S3 buckets.
>
> We do not offer hourly backups.

But I cannot find in the documentation on how to configure this feature. I checked every page in the Firebase Console but the feature is nowhere to be seen. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable private backups you have to contact the Firebase support team through their [support channel](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), they will assist you setting up daily private backup into Amazon S3 bucket or Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Hmmm, that's an odd way of working. I followed your suggestion and let you know if it indeed is the way forward.

Comment: Sure. For now, they manually configure the backups. Future releases will automate this.

Comment: Got an email from the support team. Thanks!

Comment: The email also contains a link to a blog post introducing the backup service and referencing the signup form: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/03/private-backups-for-firebase-data_21.html